# split Array with value - like String.split

Tags: javascript, arrays

In short, like this:

```
> l = ['asdf', '<br>', 'lorem', 'ipsum', '<hr>', 'dollar', 'sit', 'amex']
> l.split(/<.+>/)
[
  [ 'asdf' ] ,
  [ 'lorem', 'ipsum' ] ,
  [ 'dollar', 'sit', 'amex' ]
]
```

I wrote `join`-and-`split` one, but it seem slow with large array.

Is there any better solutions? `indexOf()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple loop would do:

```
var result = [[]];
for (var i = 0; i < l.length; ++i) {
    if (/^<.+>$/.test(l[i]) {
        // start a new inner array
        result.push([]);
    } else {
        // append to the current inner array
        result[result.length-1].push(l[i]);
    }
}
```